# Slow Type Creation in System.Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, system.reflection

I'm working on a project that requires heavy use of System.Reflection.Emit to emit a compiled version of the source code, however, I have noticed a slowness when I go to emit the entire thing (I've only been emitting part of it for testing). Namely, calling the "TypeBuilder.CreateType()" method for 946 types takes over 75 seconds, I would partially chalk this up to the sheer volume of data I'm emitting, it's a 3.01mb dll which expands to a 60mb file when decompiled with ILDasm.

Now, the rest of the emitting process for this data only takes about 40 seconds total, (and those 40 seconds include emitting quite a bit of debug data) so I'm wondering why this lone method takes so much time. Does anyone know? And are there any ways I can decrease this time?

Comment: On the outside chance you're using the 2.0 Framework, there was a bug where a O(n^2) algorithm was unnecessarily being used in `CreateType` causing poor performance. Hotfix here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970924

Comment: Ah, that would be why, I am using the 2.0 Framework. (don't ask why :P) Good to know this is one of the very few computers that would actually expierence the low performance.